# Where to find proof for the remainder formula of the interpolation in two variables

Tags: numerical-methods, interpolation, approximation-theory, lagrange-interpolation, multivariate-polynomial

Professor showed this result in the lecture without giving any proof (after proving the existence of the interpolating polynomial in two variables). I've been trying to prove it myself or find a book where is proved but I failed. This is the theorem:

Let

$$ x_0 < x_1 < \cdots < x_n \in [a, b], \quad y_0 < y_1 < \cdots < y_m \in [c, d],$$

$$ M = \{ (x_i, y_j) : 0 \leq i \leq n, 0 \leq j \leq m \}, \quad f \in \mathcal{C}^{m + n + 2}([a,b] \times [c,d]), $$

$$ p \in \Pi_{n, m} : p(x_i, y_j) = f(x_i, y_j) \quad  \forall 0 \leq i \leq n, 0 \leq j \leq m. $$

Then, for all $(x, y) \in (x_0, x_n) \times (y_0, y_m)$ exist $\xi, \xi' \in (x_0, x_n), \eta, \eta' \in (y_0, y_m)$ such that

$$ f(x, y) - p(x, y) = \frac{1}{(n + 1)!} \frac{\partial^{n + 1} f(\xi, y)}{\partial x^{n + 1}} \prod_{i = 0}^n (x - x_i) $$

$$ + \frac{1}{(m + 1)!} \frac{\partial^{m + 1} f(x, \eta)}{\partial y^{m + 1}} \prod_{j = 0}^m (y - y_j) $$

$$ - \frac{1}{(n + 1)! (m + 1)!} \frac{\partial^{n + m + 2} f(\xi', \eta')}{\partial x^{n + 1} \partial y^{m + 1}} \prod_{i = 0}^n (x - x_i) \prod_{j = 0}^m (y - y_j) $$

I appreciate any kind of help, even if it is only from where could I start the proof.

Edit 1 (clarification):

$$ \Pi_{n, m} = \{ p(x, y) = \sum_{i = 0}^n \sum_{j = 0}^m a_{i,j} x^i y^j : a_{i, j} \in \mathbb{R} \quad \forall 0 \leq i \leq n, 0 \leq j \leq m \} $$

Comment: After quite some research, I could find the formula in [this paper](https://core.ac.uk/download/pdf/81212512.pdf), equation (13). They mention two proofs: one can be found [here](https://www.jstage.jst.go.jp/article/tmj1911/18/0/18_0_309/_pdf), sections 2 and 3. There are quite a few steps and I haven't had time yet to look into all the details. I can't find the reference for the second proof.

Comment: @dvdgrgrtt I already read that paper but I found it too much obscure. Now I've found a explanation in [this book](https://archive.org/details/analysisofnumeri00isaa) in chapter 6 section 6, but it doesn't explain the concrete steps and I'm managing to figure them out.

Comment: Your reference seems interesting, thanks! I'll try to work out the details and let you know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let

$$X_{- 1}(x) = 1,\quad X_{i}(x) = \prod_{k = 0}^{i}\left( x - x_{k} \right)\quad\forall 0 \leq i \leq n $$

$$ Y_{- 1}(y) = 1,\quad Y_{j}(y) = \prod_{l = 0}^{j}\left( y - y_{l} \right)\quad\forall 0 \leq j \leq m $$

Considering $f( \cdot ,y) \in C^{n + 1}$ as a univariate function, we'll have by the Newton form for a single variable for interpolation

$$ f(x,y) = \sum_{i = 0}^{n}X_{i - 1}(x)f\left\lbrack x_{0},\ldots,x_{i};y \right\rbrack + X_{n}(x)f\left\lbrack x_{0},\ldots,x_{n},x;y \right\rbrack $$

where

$$ f\left\lbrack x_{0},\ldots,x_{i};y \right\rbrack = \left( f( \cdot ,y) \right)\left\lbrack x_{0},\ldots,x_{i} \right\rbrack $$

Now, $f\left\lbrack x_{0},\ldots,x_{i};y \right\rbrack$ for
$0 \leq k \leq n$ are also univariate functions wrt $y$.
Because it implicitely depends on (f \in C^{n + m + 2}) by the recursive formula of divided differences, we'll have
$f\left\lbrack x_{0},\ldots,x_{i};y \right\rbrack \in C^{m + 1}$ so we can apply Newton formula

$$f\left\lbrack x_{0},\ldots,x_{i};y \right\rbrack = \sum_{j = 0}^{m}Y_{j - 1}(y)f\left\lbrack x_{0},\ldots,x_{i};y_{0},\ldots,y_{j} \right\rbrack + Y_{m}(y)f\left\lbrack x_{0},\ldots,x_{i};y_{0},\ldots,y_{m},y \right\rbrack$$

where

$$f\left\lbrack x_{0},\ldots,x_{i};y_{0},\ldots,y_{j} \right\rbrack = \left( f\left\lbrack x_{0},\ldots,x_{i}; \cdot \right\rbrack \right)\left\lbrack y_{0},\ldots,y_{m} \right\rbrack$$

So if we substitute

$$f(x,y) = \sum_{i = 0}^{n}X_{i - 1}(x)\left( \sum_{j = 0}^{m}Y_{j - 1}(y)f\left\lbrack x_{0},\ldots,x_{i};y_{0},\ldots,y_{j} \right\rbrack + Y_{m}(y)f\left\lbrack x_{0},\ldots,x_{i};y_{0},\ldots,y_{m},y \right\rbrack \right)$$
$$+ X_{n}(x)f\left\lbrack x_{0},\ldots,x_{n},x;y \right\rbrack$$
$$= \sum_{i = 0}^{n}\sum_{j = 0}^{m}X_{i - 1}(x)Y_{j - 1}(y)f\left\lbrack x_{0},\ldots,x_{i};y_{0},\ldots,y_{j} \right\rbrack$$
$$+ Y_{m}(y)\sum_{i = 0}^{n}X_{i - 1}(x)f\left\lbrack x_{0},\ldots,x_{i};y_{0},\ldots,y_{m},y \right\rbrack + X_{n}(x)f\left\lbrack x_{0},\ldots,x_{n},x;y \right\rbrack$$

Let

$$p^\ast (x,y) = \sum_{i = 0}^{n}\sum_{j = 0}^{m}X_{i - 1}(x)Y_{j - 1}(y)f\left\lbrack x_{0},\ldots,x_{i};y_{0},\ldots,y_{j} \right\rbrack \in \Pi_{n,m}$$

$$r(x,y) = Y_{m}(y)\sum_{i = 0}^{n}X_{i - 1}(x)f\left\lbrack x_{0},\ldots,x_{i};y_{0},\ldots,y_{m},y \right\rbrack + X_{n}(x)f\left\lbrack x_{0},\ldots,x_{n},x;y \right\rbrack$$

So we have $f(x,y) = p^\ast (x,y) + r(x,y)$. And it is obvious that

$$X_{n}\left( x_{i} \right) = 0,\ Y_{m}\left( y_{j} \right) = 0\quad\forall 0 \leq i \leq n,\ 0 \leq j \leq m$$

So we have $r\left( x_{i},y_{j} \right) = 0\ \forall i,j$. I. e.,
$p^{\ast \left( x_{i},y_{j} \right)} = f\left( x_{i},y_{j} \right)\ \forall i,j$.
By the uniqueness of the interpolator polynomial in $\Pi_{n,m}$ we have that  $p(x,y) = p^\ast (x,y)$. So
$f(x,y) - p(x,y) = r(x,y)$.

Now, if we consider
$f\left\lbrack x;y_{0},\ldots,y_{m} \right\rbrack$, we know that

$$f\left\lbrack x;y_{0},\ldots,y_{m} \right\rbrack = \left( f\lbrack x; \cdot \rbrack \right)\left\lbrack y_{0},\ldots,y_{m},y \right\rbrack$$

Now, by the definition of divided differences

$$\left( f\left\lbrack \cdot ;y_{0},\ldots,y_{m},y \right\rbrack \right)\lbrack x\rbrack = \left( f\left\lbrack \cdot ;y_{0},\ldots,y_{m},y \right\rbrack \right)(x) = f\left\lbrack x;y_{0},\ldots,y_{m} \right\rbrack$$

So we can consider it as a function of $x$. Because it implicitely depends on $f \in C^{n + m + 2}$ it will be at least $C^{n + 1}$ so we can apply Newton formula

$$f\left\lbrack x;y_{0},\ldots,y_{m},y \right\rbrack = \sum_{i = 0}^{n}X_{i - 1}(x)f\left\lbrack x_{0},\ldots,x_{i};y_{0},\ldots,y_{m},y \right\rbrack + X_{n}(x)f\left\lbrack x_{0},\ldots,x_{n},x;y_{0},\ldots,y_{m},y \right\rbrack$$

Manipulating,

$$Y_{m}(y)f\left\lbrack x;y_{0},\ldots,y_{m},y \right\rbrack =$$
$$Y_{m}(y)\sum_{i = 0}^{n}X_{i - 1}(x)f\left\lbrack x_{0},\ldots,x_{i};y_{0},\ldots,y_{m},y \right\rbrack + Y_{m}(y)X_{n}(x)f\left\lbrack x_{0},\ldots,x_{n},x;y_{0},\ldots,y_{m},y \right\rbrack$$

$$ Y_{m}(y)\sum_{i = 0}^{n}X_{i - 1}(x)f\left\lbrack x_{0},\ldots,x_{i};y_{0},\ldots,y_{m},y \right\rbrack = $$
$$Y_{m}(y)f\left\lbrack x;y_{0},\ldots,y_{m},y \right\rbrack - Y_{m}(y)X_{n}(x)f\left\lbrack x_{0},\ldots,x_{n},x;y_{0},\ldots,y_{m},y \right\rbrack$$

We remember that

$$r(x,y) = Y_{m}(y)\sum_{i = 0}^{n}X_{i - 1}(x)f\left\lbrack x_{0},\ldots,x_{i};y_{0},\ldots,y_{m},y \right\rbrack + X_{n}(x)f\left\lbrack x_{0},\ldots,x_{n},x;y \right\rbrack$$

So if we substitute

$$r(x,y) = X_{n}(x)f\left\lbrack x_{0},\ldots,x_{n},x;y \right\rbrack + Y_{m}(y)f\left\lbrack x;y_{0},\ldots,y_{m},y \right\rbrack - X_{n}(x)Y_{m}(y)f\left\lbrack x_{0},\ldots,x_{n},x;y_{0},\ldots,y_{m},y \right\rbrack$$

Now,

$$f\left\lbrack x_{0},\ldots,x_{n},x;y \right\rbrack = \left( f\lbrack \cdot ,y\rbrack \right)\left\lbrack x_{0},\ldots,x_{n},x \right\rbrack,\quad f\left\lbrack x;y_{0},\ldots,y_{m},y \right\rbrack = \left( f(x, \cdot ) \right)\left\lbrack y_{0},\ldots,y_{m},y \right\rbrack$$

Applying mean value theorem for univariate divided differences, we have that exist
$\xi \in \left( x_{0},x_{n} \right),\ \eta \in \left( y_{0},y_{m} \right)$ such that

$$f\left\lbrack x_{0},\ldots,x_{n},x;y \right\rbrack = \frac{1}{(n + 1)!} \cdot \frac{\partial^{n + 1}f}{\partial x^{n + 1}}(\xi,y)$$

$$f\left\lbrack x;y_{0},\ldots,y_{m},y \right\rbrack = \frac{1}{(m + 1)!} \cdot \frac{\partial^{m + 1}f}{\partial y^{m + 1}}(x,\eta)$$

Finally we consider
$f\left\lbrack x_{0},\ldots,x_{n},x;y_{0},\ldots,y_{m},y \right\rbrack$.

On the one hand,

$$f\left\lbrack x_{0},\ldots,x_{n},x;y_{0},\ldots,y_{m},y \right\rbrack = \left( f\left\lbrack \cdot ;y_{0},\ldots,y_{m},y \right\rbrack \right)\left\lbrack x_{0},\ldots,x_{n},x \right\rbrack$$

Applying mean value theorem to $f\left\lbrack \cdot ;y_{0},\ldots,y_{m},y \right\rbrack$, which we know it is $C^{n + 1}$ because it implicitely depends on $f$, we'll have that exists $\xi\prime \in \left( x_{0},x_{n} \right)$ such that

$$\left( f\left\lbrack \cdot ;y_{0},\ldots,y_{m},y \right\rbrack \right)\left\lbrack x_{0},\ldots,x_{n},x \right\rbrack = \frac{1}{(n + 1)!} \cdot \frac{\partial^{n + 1}f\left\lbrack \cdot ;y_{0},\ldots,y_{m},y \right\rbrack}{\partial x^{n + 1}}(\xi\prime)$$

Now,

$$\frac{\partial^{n + 1}f\left\lbrack \cdot ;y_{0},\ldots,y_{m},y \right\rbrack}{\partial x^{n + 1}}(\xi\prime) = \frac{\partial^{n + 1}f\left\lbrack \xi\prime;y_{0},\ldots,y_{m},y \right\rbrack}{\partial x^{n + 1}} = \left( \frac{\partial^{n + 1}f\lbrack\xi\prime; \cdot \rbrack}{\partial x^{n + 1}} \right)\left\lbrack y_{0},\ldots,y_{m},y \right\rbrack$$

And $\frac{\partial^{n + 1}f\lbrack\xi\prime; \cdot \rbrack}{\partial x^{n + 1}}$
is an expression obtained derivating $n + 1$ times wrt $x$ the function
$f \in C^{n + m + 2}$. So this function will be at least
$C^{n + m + 2 - (n + 1)} = C^{m + 1}$ and we can apply the mean value theorem, so it exists $\eta\prime \in \left( y_{0},y_{m} \right)$ such that

$$\left( \frac{\partial^{n + 1}f\lbrack\xi\prime; \cdot \rbrack}{\partial x^{n + 1}} \right)\left\lbrack y_{0},\ldots,y_{m},y \right\rbrack = \frac{1}{(m + 1)!} \cdot \frac{\partial^{n + 1}\frac{\partial^{m + 1}f\lbrack\xi\prime;\eta\prime\rbrack}{\partial y^{m + 1}}}{\partial x^{n + 1}}$$

Now,

$$f\lbrack\xi\prime;\eta\prime\rbrack = \left( f( \cdot ,\eta\prime) \right)\lbrack\xi\prime\rbrack = \left( f( \cdot ,\eta\prime) \right)(\xi\prime) = f(\xi\prime,\eta\prime)$$

So

$$\frac{\partial^{n + 1}\frac{\partial^{m + 1}f\lbrack\xi\prime;\eta\prime\rbrack}{\partial y^{m + 1}}}{\partial x^{n + 1}} = \frac{\partial^{n + 1}\frac{\partial^{m + 1}f(\xi\prime,\eta\prime)}{\partial y^{m + 1}}}{\partial x^{n + 1}} = \frac{\partial^{n + m + 2}f}{\partial x^{n + 1}y^{m + 1}}(\xi\prime,\eta\prime)$$

So we have

$$f\left\lbrack x_{0},\ldots,x_{n},x;y_{0},\ldots,y_{m},y \right\rbrack = \frac{1}{(n + 1)!(m + 1)!} \cdot \frac{\partial^{n + m + 2}f}{\partial x^{n + 1}y^{m + 1}}(\xi\prime,\eta\prime)$$

Substituting in $r(x,y)$ we'll have

$$r(x,y) = \frac{1}{(n + 1)!} \cdot \frac{\partial^{n + 1}f}{\partial x^{n + 1}}(\xi,y) \cdot X_{n}(x) + \frac{1}{(m + 1)!} \cdot \frac{\partial^{m + 1}f}{\partial y^{m + 1}}(x,\eta) \cdot Y_{m}(y)$$
$$- \frac{1}{(n + 1)!(m + 1)!} \cdot \frac{\partial^{n + m + 2}f}{\partial x^{n + 1}y^{m + 1}}(\xi\prime,\eta\prime)X_{n}(x)Y_{m}(y)$$

As we wanted to show.

Answer (score 0):

Too long for comment and also don’t have enough reputation

I had hoped that you would have started the calculations, especially as $f(\xi,y)$ occurs on the right side of $$\dfrac{\partial^{n+1} f(\xi,y)}{\partial^{n+1} x}$$ which makes the term
$$
\dfrac{\partial^{n+1} f(\xi,y)}{\partial^{n+1} x}\prod_{i=0}^n(x-x_i)
$$
confusing and I have to guess whether this means
$$
f(\xi,y)\cdot\dfrac{\partial^{n+1} }{\partial^{n+1} x}\prod_{i=0}^n(x-x_i)
$$

Anyway, your formula is a direct consequence of the multivariate Taylor expansion, here the bivariate version in two variables. Of course, I could type what my textbook says and use very likely a different notation than your textbook uses, so let me instead directly ask you what you know about Taylor's theorem for functions $f\, : \,\mathbb{R}^2\longrightarrow \mathbb{R}\;$?

Comment: The notation $\frac{\partial^{n+1}f(\xi,y)}{\partial x^{n+1}}$ means that you have to evaluate the $(n+1)$st partial derivative of $f(x,y)$ with respect to $x$ at the point $(\xi, y)$. For instance, if $f(x,y)=e^{xy}$ and $n=0$, then $\frac{\partial f(\xi,y)}{\partial x}=y e^{\xi y}$. I agree that this is not the clearest notation.

Also, the analogy with the Taylor expansion is not completely certain, since the three error terms have different orders of differentiation.

Comment: @dvdgrgrtt already explained the notation. Regarding to the Taylor formula, I doubt it can be of use in this case, since it involves repeated derivatives in one point and this is just interpolation. The proof for the univariate case uses Rolle theorem inductively and has nothing to do with Taylor